gtsummary doesn't print tables in jupyter notebook in vscode
I've been trying to print some nice tables using the package gtsummary in R, but it keeps outputting the source code, when the expected output should be a formatted table:

Data used for rendering the table:

Using RStudio and RMarkdown is very easy to do it. However, now I'm accessing a cluster through VSCode Jupyter Notebook, and I really would like to print the tables the same way I did with RStudio.
ggplots are rendering just fine, the only issue I'm currently having seems to be gtsummary table rendering.
Maybe a extension or package I forgot installing? Can you help me with that?
Thanks!

That is not the source code it is outputting, it is the HTML for your table. Did your try wrapping the tbl_summary(trial) in display_html(), specifically like display_html(tbl_summary(trial)), as outlined here and here in answer to 'R - how to embed HTML code into Jupyter notebook output?'?
